# Android 2.2 SDK / JAVA - error uploading file/posting params via HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, android, http-headers

I'm getting this error, though in my postMap I definitely specify a post var "eventTitle", what the heck is going on?:

> 01-03 11:52:29.758:
>   INFO/System.out(27682): Server
>   response is: **Warning**:
>   htmlspecialchars(): Invalid multibyte
>   sequence in argument in
>   **/home/staging/public_html/system/library/request.php**
>   on line **31****Warning**:
>   session_start(): Cannot send session
>   cookie - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/staging/public_html/index.php:100)
>   in
>   **/home/staging/public_html/system/library/session.php**
>   on line **11****Warning**:
>   session_start(): Cannot send session
>   cache limiter - headers already sent
>   (output started at
>   /home/staging/public_html/index.php:100)
>   in
>   **/home/staging/public_html/system/library/session.php**
>   on line **11****Warning**:
>   Cannot modify header information -
>   headers already sent by (output
>   started at
>   /home/staging/public_html/index.php:100)
>   in
>   **/home/staging/public_html/index.php**
>   on line **181****Warning**:
>   Cannot modify header information -
>   headers already sent by (output
>   started at
>   /home/staging/public_html/index.php:100)
>   in
>   **/home/staging/public_html/system/library/currency.php**
>   on line
>   **45**846

```
public String postHTTPMultipart(LinkedHashMap<String, String> postMap, String apiCall, String token, String imagePath) {

     private String header1 = "api-key";
     private String apiKey = "xxx";
     private String header2 = "User-agent";
    private String headerValue2 = "Testing";
     private String header3 = "Accept:";
     private String headerValue3 = "application/json";
     private String header4 = "session-token";

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        DataInputStream inStream = null;

        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;

        byte[] buffer;

        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

        try {

            // ------------------ CLIENT REQUEST

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(imagePath));

            //open a URL connection to the Servlet
            URL url = new URL(apiCall);

            //open a HTTP connection to the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            //allow Inputs
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            //allow Outputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            //don't use a cached copy.
            conn.setUseCaches(false);

            //use a post method.
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.addRequestProperty(header1, apiKey);
            conn.addRequestProperty(header2, headerValue2);
            conn.addRequestProperty(header3, headerValue3);
            conn.addRequestProperty(header4, token);

            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

            //add post parameters
            String urlParameters = null;
            for (Entry<String, String> entry : postMap.entrySet()) {

                String key = entry.getKey();
                String value = entry.getValue();

                String append = key + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8") + "&";

                if (urlParameters != null) {
                    urlParameters = urlParameters + append;
                } else {
                    urlParameters = append;
                }

            }

            urlParameters = urlParameters.substring(0, urlParameters.length() - 1);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";" + " eventImage=\"" + imagePath + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            //add post parameters here?
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd + urlParameters + lineEnd);

            // close streams
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            System.out.println("From ServletCom CLIENT REQUEST:" + ex);
        }

        catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("From ServletCom CLIENT REQUEST:" + ioe);
        }

        // ------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE

        String response = null;
        try {
            inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            while ((response = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Server response is: " + response);
                System.out.println("");
            }
            inStream.close();

        } catch (IOException ioex) {
            Log.e("IOException", "Exception", ioex);
            System.out.println("From (ServerResponse): " + ioex);

        }

        return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem in on the php side.  You're probably sending output and then later in the script trying to modify headers, but you can't do so because they've already been sent.

Comment: I don't think it's on the php side, the API works with curl.  Maybe it's where I'm declaring my posted parameters?